# Is Sleep statement allowed in spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a requirement of add sleep statement if i am unable to consume message and want to retry after 5s. To do this do i need to set any configuration properties?

```
rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, Object>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, Object>> record)
                throws Exception {
            while (record.hasNext()) {
                ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = record.next();
               boolean flag=false;
                while(flag){
                    flag= processmessage(record.value())
                if(!flag)
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Currently, i am unable to run my job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sleep in spark streaming application.

But wait,

Spark streaming job runs micro batches and we define the stream interval time which is usually in few seconds ( could be 1s, 2s,... etc ). If you use sleep in your spark streaming code, it will take additional time to finish running each micro batch. This might impact the performance if data is coming very frequently.

It totally depends on application requirement whether sleep will make any performance issue or delay or it might just not impact if data is coming after long intervals.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ajay , my issue is solved. Job is failed bcoz of other issue. Thanks for response